# Nameserver working for all TLDs except .org

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I've recently set up a private name server (`ns1.mediamechanic.net` / `ns2.mediamechanic.net`), and it appears to be working for everything except our `.org` domains (see obapps.org).

As far as I can tell, the failure is happening before the request ever makes its way to our server, so presumably something is wrong on the side of our registrar (eNom).

When I do a trace on a working TLD (.com, .net) I get this:

```
===================================================
Sending request to "e,gtld-servers.net" (192.12.94.30)
===================================================
Received referral response - DNS servers for "iclaimpreview.com":
-> ns1.mediamechanic.net (216.114.240.114)
-> ns2.mediamechanic.net (208.115.254.250)
===================================================
Sending request to "ns1.mediamechanic.net" (216.144.240.114)
===================================================
Received authoritative (AA) response:
-> Answer: A-record for iclaimpreview.com = 216.114.240.114
-> Authority: NS-record for iclaimpreview.com = ns2.dallas-idc.com
-> Authority: NS-record for iclaimpreview.com = ns2.dallas-idc.com
===================================================
```

A .org yields this:

```
===================================================
Attempting to resolve DNS server name "ns1.mediamechanic.net" (details not logged)
===================================================
Failed to resolve DNS server name - error: No such host is known
===================================================
Attempting to resolve DNS server name "ns2.mediamechanic.net" (details not logged)
===================================================
Failed to resolve DNS server name - error: No such host is known
===================================================
Failed to resolve - no more DNS servers left to try
===================================================
```

It seems that for the .org, it’s unable even to find the name server, which doesn’t make a ton of sense, so I’m at a loss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error messages in the question actually say it all, the problem is simply that the names `ns{1,2}.mediamechanic.net` referenced in your `NS` records do not resolve at this point in time.

For `.com`/`.net` it "kind of works" despite there being an obvious problem because many resolvers just use the received glue without looking up the authoritative records. Both these TLDs are on the same set of nameservers so glue is provided in both these cases.

In the case of `.org` that TLD is on an entirely different set of nameservers so there is no glue there. The resolver will then try to look these names up and that is currently impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen your case at this [website](http://www.intodns.com/obapps.org)

you have not created records to pointing this domain on your nameserver

```
[root@ ~]# ping ns1.mediamechanic.net
ping: unknown host ns1.mediamechanic.net
[root@ ~]# ping ns2.mediamechanic.net
ping: unknown host ns2.mediamechanic.net
```

Comment: The main domain hasn't been flipped yet, so I wouldn't expect a ping to work. You can however do nslookup's on any of the .coms or .nets we've transferred and get the expected results, since the glue record has been set up with our registrar. (e.g. `nslookup skyjuke.com`)

Comment: just recheck your parent is different with your nameservers reported with intodns.com

Comment: @Sam That actually has the same problem but I gather it may work depending on what checks are done. It's a serious issue that `ns{1,2}.mediamechanic.net` do not resolve when you have delegated domains there. Glue is *NOT* authoritative, it's not satisfactory to have a situation where the authoritative records can not be looked up.